# Parametrized Query Using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

Is it possible to create a standard method to execute parametrized queries from **Java to SQL Server** using JDBC?

Here's how i create a pool of connections to the db:

```
    static ConnectionPool pool;
    public static void crearPool(){
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Driver driver = (Driver) c.newInstance();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=STAZIONE;";
            pool = new ConnectionPool("local",5, 20, 40, 180, url, "b_lightyear", "BeyondInfinity");
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {/*Error Message*/}
    }
```

And here's how i think a standard method for every **DML Query** would be:

```
    public static int QueryDML(String consulta,Object []data){
        int result = 0;
        PreparedStatement prpdStm = null;
        try{
            Connection cnx = pool.getConnection(clsConexion.espera);
            if(conexion!=null){
                prpdStm = conexion.prepareStatement(consulta,,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                for(int position =1; position<data.length;position++){
                    prpdStm.setObject(position, data[position-1]);
                }result = prpdStm.executeUpdate();
            } else{/*Message*/}
        } catch (SQLException ex) {/*Error Message*/}
        return result;
    }
```

What i want to know is if *`prpdStm.setObject(position, data[position-1]);`* will function for any type of data ->(`String`, `Integer`, `Double`, etc...)?

Comment: You seem to have the code... have you tried it?

Comment: @Jason No yet, i've made it, but then i asked myself if there would be any problem by setting the values of parameters by using setObject, now i know it doesn't has any problem, but before that i would like to get some opinions about this way of executing a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i want to know is if prpdStm.setObject(position, data[position-1]); will function for any type of data ->(String, Integer, Double, etc...)?

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer per the [`PreparedStatement.setObject()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) -

> The JDBC specification specifies a standard mapping from Java Object types to SQL types.   The given argument will be converted to the corresponding SQL type before being sent to the database.

Comment: Thanks, did you check out the whole code from the method?, do you think it's a great way to make a method that you'll send the query (example "INSERT INTO [TABLE & COLUMNS]  VALUES (?,?,?)") and an array containing the value of each parameter? or do you thinks there's a better way?

Comment: I did not perform a complete [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but you could post over there for one. It's a *terrible* idea to silently swallow Exception like that. I would probably store the query in a separate query xml file. Also, I'd probably inject the pool.

Comment: How do you make those things you said, store the query un xml file and inject the pool ?

Comment: Try looking on the web for dependency injection and [MyBatis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyBatis) or even [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) can do that sort of thing, but that type of question is off-topic for a reason.

Comment: could you please give an example?